# Dialog box with variable number of input fields

Tags: inputfield, dialog-window

I am trying create a dialog window for updating a variable number of parameters $\beta_i$. Here are the relevant bits of my code, which first constructs a list of $\beta_i$ parameters, then constructs the dialog box based on the number of parameters that I specify, and then executes the dialog box.

```
nparams=3;
params=Table[Symbol["B"<>ToString[x]],{x,1,nparams}];
testgrid={};
For[n=1,n<=nparams,n++,
   row={StringJoin["B",ToString[n]],InputField[params[[n]],Expression};
   AppendTo[testgrid,row]
]
AppendTo[testgrid, {CancelButton[],DefaultButton[DialogReturn[]]}];
CreateDialog[Grid[testgrid,Spacings->{1,Automatic},Alignment->Left],Modal->True]
```

When I run this code, the dialog box pops up just fine, but the "params" list of parameters is not getting updated. I am guessing that my mistake has something to do with not directly putting the parameter in the InputField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Dynamic` around the symbol inside of `InputField`

```
nparams = 3;
params = Table[Symbol["B" <> ToString[x]], {x, 1, nparams}];
testgrid = {};
For[n = 1, n <= nparams, n++, row = {StringJoin["B", ToString[n]],
   InputField[Dynamic[Evaluate@params[[n]]], Expression]}; AppendTo[testgrid, row]]
AppendTo[testgrid, {CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[]]}];
CreateDialog[Grid[testgrid, Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left], Modal -> True]
```

If the code needs to work after the values are set for the first time, you can apply this modification:

```
params = Table["B" <> ToString[x], {x, 1, nparams}];
testgrid = {};
For[n = 1, n <= nparams, n++, row = {StringJoin["B", ToString[n]],
  ToExpression["InputField[Dynamic[" <> params[[n]] <> "],Expression]"]};
  AppendTo[testgrid, row]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had attempted using the `Dynamic` command, but didn't have the `Evaluate@` so it wasn't working. This looks like it will do the trick.